# sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly must be set

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop

MSBuild SonarQube is raising the issue 'sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly must be set' when using FxCop rules in the QualityProfile. See exception below.

It is working fine with other StyleCop and C# rules.
I had a look to similar posts but couldn't find a solution.

I am using :

```
C:\Sonar\sonarqube-5.2
C:\Sonar\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2
```

The following plugins are installed:
    Plugin C# 4.3
    Plugin StyleCop 1.1

Targeting the following sample project:

```
C:\Sonar\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\csharp\ConsoleApplication1
```

I am executing the following commands :

```
cd Sonar\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0.2\

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"MyProjectKey" /n:"MyProjectName" /v:"MyProjectVersion"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Sonar\sonar-examples-master\projects\languages\csharp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.csproj" /t:Rebuild

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

I have tried to declare the assembly location in the .csproj file but without success. What does the expected path looks like ?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SonarQubeSetting Include="sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly">
        <Value>path to dll</Value>
    </SonarQubeSetting>
</ItemGroup>
```

Thank you for your help !

Exception :

```
10:33:14.564 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpFxCopProvider$CSharpF
xCopSensor@1eeeda8
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 12.017s
Final Memory: 14M/113M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher
.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102
)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find the assembly "C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Fx
CopSdk.dll" provided by the property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly".
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java
:88)
        at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkAssemblyProperty(FxCo
pConfiguration.java:115)
        at org.sonar.plugins.fxcop.FxCopConfiguration.checkProperties(FxCopConfi
guration.java:97)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading: You shouldn't try to set the `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly` property. What is probably happening is that you are running the analysis from a machine on which Visual Studio is not installed, and FxCop is not being triggered during `msbuild` itself (as part of the "Code Analysis" MSBuild task).

The upcoming SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild version 1.1 already includes a better error message for the case when FxCop rules are enabled, but FxCop isn't installed. See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-161

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 installed on my machine, and I can find FxCop into the following folder :
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop

Do I need to install another version of FxCop ?

Comment: Since I have not installed VS2013, I have installed MS Build for VS2013 [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760)I have just installed FxCop 10 following the instructions described at this [link](http://www.fluxbytes.com/microsoft/download-fxcop-10/) but I still get the issue.

Comment: Yes I suspect that you will need Visual Studio 2013 to work smoothly with MSBuild 12. However, you can try to set the environment variable `%VisualStudioVersion%` to `11.0`  and see if this forces MSBuild 12 to look for your Visual Studio 11 installation.

Comment: In fact there is a better way to specify which version of Visual Studio to use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By default, by installing Visual Studio on the build server, `fxcopcmd.exe` is stored here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue will get fixed if you make fxcop assembly to point your application dll as shown below.

sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe
sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=APPLICATIONNAME/bin/APPLICATIONNAME.dll

Note: Please be sure that you are giving the correct path to point to bin folder.